# How to disable "Delete Selection" option in 1st Stage Recycle Bin?

Tags: recycle-bin

I have a following requirement in SharePoint 2010.

We need to disable the "Delete Selection" menu option from the recycle bin for SharePoint members. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Although it is certainly possible modifying the internal /_layouts/RecycleBin.aspx page, I personally stay far away from this approach for several reasons (supportability and maintenance to name only two).

Instead I'd recommend the approach outlined here http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/custom-page-security-using-sharepoint-delegate-controls with a DelegateControl.

The simplest way is then to make a copy of the original page, change the copy to fit your needs and use a redirect with the DelegateControl like this:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.IndexOf("_layouts/settings.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > 0)
    {
        Context.Response.Redirect("MySiteSettingsPage.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

A far more complicated approach would be to use the DelegateControl to directly manipulate the wssuc:ToolBarButton control via ASP.NET. Unfortunately I don't have a working example of this approach for you, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.

I couldn't find a sharepoint specific setting for this. Maybe there is one somewhere..

Anyways, Personally, I'd just edit the /_layouts/RecycleBin.aspx page and remove the button.

Create a copy of the page though before editing it.

Find the following control and add the Visible="false" Attribute :

```
<wssuc:ToolBarButton runat="server"
                        id="ButtonDeleteItems"
                        Text="<%$Resources:wss,recyclebin_deleteselection%>"
                        ToolTip="<%$Resources:wss,recyclebin_deleteselection%>"
                        NavigateUrl="javascript:deleteItems()"
                        AccessKey="X"
                        ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/delitem.gif"
                        Visible="false"
                        />
```